# Using Swift Framework inside Objective C Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-framework

I have an Swift Framework which works perfectly inside Swift Projects. Now I am trying to use it inside of Objective-C project.

Iv'e Change the Class to looks like:

```
@objc public class Test : NSObject {}
```

I imported the framework to the Objective-C project, added it to the **Embedded Binaries** and to the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**.

In the ViewController.m I imported the framework like this:

```
#import <SwiftFramework/SwiftFramework-Swift.h>
```

And I try to create instance of type Test:

```
Test* test = [[Test alloc] init];
```

Test is recognize but when I try to build it to iPhone it's failed with the reason of:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC14SwiftFramework4Test", referenced from:
```

And if I build it to a simulator it failed with the reason of:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC14SwiftFramework4Test", referenced from:
```

I've tried to add the **i386** and **arm64** to the **Valid Architectures**,

I've tried to change the **Build Active Architecture Only** to **No**.

I've found a lot of solution which did not help me solve the issue.

I'll appreciate any help, Thank you.

## **SOLVED:**

**Build Setting -> Build Settings -> Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries -> YES**

I updated the framework and the Objective-C project.

Comment: `Target` > `Build Setting` > `Defines Module` to YES try this

Comment: It is defined as Yes by default

Comment: what is the value of Architectures (not Valid Architectures) ?